# How can i delete a row from the database with coldfusion and ajax

Tags: ajax, database, coldfusion

I'm having problems with deleting a database row in real time. I mean deleting a outputted row from the database without loading the page. I use coldfusion. And i know the best way is to use Ajax but i'm not good with ajax.

This is how the page look like..

```
<cfquery datasource="xyz" name="get_it">
    SELECT *
    FROM teachers
</cfquery>

<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Age</td>
      <td>Manage</td>
  </tr>

      <Cfoutput query="get_it">
   <tr>
      <td>#name#</td>
      <td>#age#</td>
      <td><a href="delete_teacher.cfm?id=#teacherid#" name="del">Delete</a></td>
   </tr>
      </cfoutput>

</table>
```

=============THE DELETING PAGE==============

```
  <Cfquery datasource="xyz" name="delete_teacher">
       DELETE 
       FROM teachers
       WHERE teacherid = #id#
  </cfqquery>
```

I want when the delete link is clicked it should delete the data(both in the database and in the outputed table) without leaving the page.

Thanks.

Comment: create a component, call that component using ajax, remove the row from the page.

Comment: Also, you MUST use `cfqueryparam` if you're doing ajax calls otherwise your queries could easily be manipulated.

Comment: Give id to to del then create onclick function for that id and use ajax in jquery. Then create component and create delId services where you will type the delete quary and in success show the success message.

Comment: For deleting from view file, you have to call table view back means you have to call query for updated data table.

Comment: i don't know ajax that well, but surely theres a way after you've deleted the item from the database that you could delete the table row through ajax instead of redoing the query and re displaying the whole table? but maybe not ... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can have your ajax function return the new rows. Then you just replace the table rows on the page with the result (html) of the ajax function.

In your page:

```
<cfquery datasource="xyz" name="get_it">
SELECT *
FROM teachers
</cfquery>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>Manage</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody id="teachers">
        <Cfoutput query="get_it">
            <tr>
                <td>#name#</td>
                <td>#age#</td>
                <td><a href="delete_teacher.cfm?id=#teacherid#" onclick="doAjax(this.href);">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </cfoutput>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The ajax caller, assuming jquery:

```
<script>
function doAjax(thisUrl)
$.get( thisUrl, function( data ) {
    // REPLACE THE TBODY WITH NEW ROWS
    $( "#teachers" ).html( data );
});
return false;
</script>
```

In your ajax handler:

```
<!--- NO WHITESPACE --->
<cfsetting enableCFoutputOnly="Yes">

<!--- DELETE --->
<Cfquery datasource="xyz" name="delete_teacher">
    DELETE 
    FROM teachers
    WHERE teacherid = <cfqueryparam CFSQLType="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#url.id#">
</cfqquery>

<!--- REGENERATE --->
<cfquery datasource="xyz" name="get_it">
SELECT *
FROM teachers
</cfquery>
<Cfoutput query="get_it">
    <tr>
        <td>#name#</td>
        <td>#age#</td>
        <td><a href="delete_teacher.cfm?id=#teacherid#" onclick="doAjax(this.href);">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
</cfoutput>
```